# Mismatch in ObjectId Conversion between REST Server and Android App

Tags: java, android, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

Im encountering an issue with converting the timestamp and date of the objectId received from my REST server to a matching ObjectId hexadecimal value in my Android app. The server sends an object of timestamp and date as part of the response, and I need to generate an ObjectId that corresponds to the one stored in my MongoDB documents.

this is the first document in my Mongodb with its objectId:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a6d4ae3fe947597ff1fe23"
  },
  "content": "my first post ",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2023-07-06T14:50:22.778Z"
  },
  "hashtags": [],
  "user": {
    "$ref": "app_users",
    "$id": {
      "$oid": "648da920b40b7222a0af8cb6"
    }
  },
  "_class": "dev.social.media.security.model.Post"
}
```

[image: in my spring boot rest API i get the correct data shown here in postman]

here is where the issue turns up. in my android console i try to get the objectId of the first document and the results I get in the console doesn't match the objectId in the server and MongoDB

[image]

the problem doesn't seem to be the way I am requesting data from the server in Android because i am fetching the correct data from everything other than the objectID which doesn't match the one in Mongodb.

```
        // Make the API call to fetch the list of posts
        PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
        Call<List<Post>> call = postService.getAllPosts(authToken); // Replace page and size with your desired values
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Post>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Post>> response) {
                System.out.println("we should get the postts here " + response.body());
                System.out.println("header check " + response.headers());
                System.out.println("Status code from server" + response.isSuccessful());
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                    //Gson gson = new Gson();
                    // List<Post> responsePage = Collections.singletonList(gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Post.class));
                    // Type postListType = new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    List<Post> posts = response.body();
                    String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(posts);
                    System.out.println("Server response original: " + new Gson().toJson(posts));
                    // Set the correct post ID for each post object
  /*                  for (Post post : posts) {
                        // Assuming the server response contains a field "postId" that holds the post ID
                        ObjectId postId = post.getIdWrapper();// Replace "getPostId()" with the correct method to get the post ID from the server response
                        post.setIdWrapper(postId); // Assuming "setId()" is the method to set the post ID in your Post class
                    }
*/

                    // Log the response body
                    System.out.println("Response body: " + jsonResponse);
                    if (posts != null) {
                        // int totalPages = pageResponse.getTotalPage;
                        // long totalElements = pageResponse.getTotalElements();


                        //System.out.println("size: " + posts.size());
                        //  System.out.println("total pages: " );
                        //System.out.println("total elements: ");
                        System.out.println("get id from the original post "+ posts.get(0).getIdWrapper());
                        System.out.println("get content from original post " + posts.get(0).getContent());

                        postAdapter.setPostList(posts);


                    } else {
                        // Handle the case when the 'posts' list is null
                        System.out.println("Received null posts list");
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                    // Handle the login error here
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong displaying the post");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
```

the model class post in android

```
public class Post  {


    @SerializedName("_id")
    private ObjectId idWrapper;

    @SerializedName("content")
    private String content;

    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    private String createdAt;

    @SerializedName("updatedAt")
    private String updatedAt;

    @SerializedName("hashtags")
    private List<String> hashtags;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @SerializedName("likes")
    private List<Like> likes;

    @SerializedName("user")
    private AppUser user;




    //empty constructor
    public Post() {}

    public Post( ObjectId idWrapper, String content, String createdAt, String updatedAt, List<String> hashtags, List<Comment> comments, List<Like> likes, AppUser user) {
       this.idWrapper = idWrapper;
        this.content = content;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.hashtags = hashtags;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public ObjectId getIdWrapper() {
        return idWrapper;
    }

    public void setIdWrapper(ObjectId idWrapper) {
        this.idWrapper = idWrapper;
    }
```

Comment: Is it the only document in the collection? The timestamp part of the object IDs "64a6d4ae" is the same, it's only the random part that differs. It might be just the case that you have several documents created at 2023-07-06T14:50:22

Comment: No, I do have several other documents and none of them match the output I get. Also, in Android I made sure to output  the first document.  I specifically checked the first entry in the code I sent 
 System.out.println("get id from the original post "+ posts.get(0).getIdWrapper());. I believe the serialization of the document in Android might be the issue. Because I output the correct id  in the rest API server but when I try to a GET request in Android everything but the Id matches perfectly.